# IE 11 throws not enough storage is available to complete this operation

Tags: angularjs, memory-leaks, crash, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem in one of my angularjs applications. That is, it constantly throws the "not enough storage is available to complete this operation" error in IE 11 and in chrome it throws a different error. I thought that there are memory leaks and reviewed the code and found the bug and fixed it. It worked just fine in Chrome. And I can see the memory blocks getting deallocated in chrome. 
But strangely IE is still throwing the same error.

There are basically 2 pages (or states) in my application. One that shows list of some entries. The other one is a page which contains the angular ui-grid. The bug reproduction steps are

1. Go to the first page
2. Click on one of the entries that opens the grid
3. Go back to the first page after data is loaded into the grid.

Continue steps 1 - 3 repeatedly and after 3 times IE throws the error. This is a SPA and all these state transitions are done using angular ui-router.

I am loading some 60MB of data into the grid using ajax call. The debugger shows the error is while reading the xhr`s responseText.

Comment: I restarted machine and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that map help ... check the Browsing History in IE to see if it has enough space to hold what is being returned as the json.  (Internet Options -> General Tab -> and in the Browsing History section, click on the Settings button and verify the Disk space to use.